# Scripts to "export" Junos-like (tree) configuration data to CSV-like (table) data and back

Tags: configuration, tree, export-to-csv

I would like to have some scripts to export Junos-like configuration data to sort of "CSV-like" data (separated by tabs) and back. The sample (and **AFAIK** sufficient) input may be as follows:

```
firewall {
    filter protect {
        term "protocol bgp" {
            from {
                prefix-list {
                    bgp-peers;
                }
                protocol tcp; ## Any ideas how to preserve comments in output?
                port bgp;
            }
            then accept;
        }
        term protocol_ntp {
            from {
                prefix-list {
                    "protocol ntp";
                }
                protocol udp;
                port ntp;
            }
            then accept;
        }
    }
}
```

The expected output would be as follows (bars "|" denote places where tabs are expected):

```
firewall|filter protect|term "protocol bgp"|from|prefix-list|bgp-peers;
firewall|filter protect|term "protocol bgp"|from|protocol tcp;
firewall|filter protect|term "protocol bgp"|from|port bgp;
firewall|filter protect|term "protocol bgp"|then accept;
firewall|filter protect|term protocol_ntp|from|prefix-list|"protocol ntp";
firewall|filter protect|term protocol_ntp|from|protocol udp;
firewall|filter protect|term protocol_ntp|from|port ntp;
firewall|filter protect|term protocol_ntp|then accept;
```

At first glance, the problem seems quite easy but at second it's not because of the double-quotes.
The problem is **IMHO** reducable to "tree-to-table" and "table-to-tree" problem with some extra double-quotes handling. I honestly do not know to do that correctly...

I would prefer solutions in next order by popularity (for me): in `sed(1)` (could be very fast), in `awk(1)` (not as nice as the former one to me), in `perl(1)` (why not, if using only plain Perl with just `strict` and `warnings` modules sourced) or in **ANSI C** without extra libraries, just the base (I do not expect anybody would like to write parsers for me here at all, but one never knows).

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot easier to convert from XML, which JunOS has built-in support for:

```
show configuration | display xml
```

Or better yet, try

```
show configuration | display set
```